# SSL connection to mysql

Tags: ssl, java

У меня есть 3 файла: SSL CA File, SSL CERT File, SSL Key File.
Нужно подключиться к mysql серверу по ssl, как это делается в MySQL workbench, указывая эти файлы.

Т.е. надо как-то методу DriverManager.getConnection() передать эти файлы.

Отмечу, что коннектов может быть много к разным серверам, и у каждого будут свои сертификаты, поэтому установка глобальных свойств

```
System.setProperty("javax.net.ssl.keyStore","/CERTIFICATES/mysql4/cacert.pem");
```

свойств не подходит. 
В общем-то у меня и через  гл. установку свойств не идёт проключение

```
System.setProperty("javax.net.ssl.keyStore","c:/Work/ca.pem");
System.setProperty("javax.net.ssl.keyStorePassword","c:/Work/cert");
System.setProperty("javax.net.ssl.trustStore","c:/Work/clint-key.pem");
System.setProperty("javax.net.ssl.trustStorePassword","c:/Work/ca.crt");
```

Валится:

> MESSAGE:
> java.security.NoSuchAlgorithmException:
> Error constructing implementation
> (algorithm: Default, provider:
> SunJSSE, class:
> sun.security.ssl.SSLContextImpl$DefaultSSLContext)

Comment: @xPro, может это поможет: http://stackoverflow.com/a/6369789/2902432